# displaying a powerpoint presentation in the background of a video clip

Tags: video-sequence-editor

How do I display a powerpoint presentation in the background of a video clip, changing the slides in time with the speaker talking in the foreground? thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to transition between slides? Do you have the individual slides as images? Or do you have an actual presentation in powerpoint?

Answer (score 1):

Blender doesn't have support for reading powerpoint presentations. However you can save the presentation as a sequence of images and display the image sequence within blender.

1. In powerpoint choose "Save as" and select an image format.
2. In blender you can easily setup a plane to display the images with the [import image as plane addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Planes_from_Images).
3. Adjust the texture to display an image sequence.

[image]

You can also find the same settings in blender internals image settings.